# Enhanced for each loop optimization

Tags: foreach

I have tried multiple things but is there a way i can optimize this code to work within 2 seconds for p and q of size greater than 50000 in Java 7. p and q are 2 array lists of different sizes.

```
for(Integer x:q){
            for(Integer y: p){
                    counter++;
                    if(x<= y){                              
                    ls.add(count);                                    
                    }            
            }
            //some code logic here based on ls
               ls.clear();
               counter=0;
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code has 2 parts. A nested loop and the remaining code (some logic). Which part is taking more than 2s ?

Comment: The nested loop  because remaining code is plain if based on size of ls.